# How share folder with QEMU between MacOS host and Linux guest?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, macos, virtfs

I am trying to run a Linux Debian with qemu with MacOS Big Sur host.

Unfortunately **virtfs** doesn't work on Mac and there is no easy alternative that I have found.

Is there a way to share folders?

Thanks!!

**EDIT:**

This is what I need: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/122420 but it is still in progress !!

Thanks to all!

Comment: One could also have a look a similar question asked on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420911/how-share-folder-in-qemu-with-plan9-virtfs-between-macos-host-and-linux-guest). Multiple options are discussed in more details.

Answer (score 1):

You could install SAMBA on your Debian image, and whatever folders you share with SAMBA will be accesable via *network locations* in your Mac's finder. If you wish to go that route, here are instructions on setting up SAMBA in Debian Buster: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-set-up-a-samba-server-on-debian-10-buster.

Or you can set up a file sharing on your Mac to share a folder that can be accessed by Debian. If you wish to go that route, here are instructions on sharing folders on your Big Sur: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-file-sharing-on-mac-mh17131/mac

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know if there is any way to do it with plan9/virtfs?

Comment: Following the PR you posted in the question, 9p virtfs support on macOS is still in progress but close to getting merged into QEMU.